# Align two NIFTI files with different origins and sizes?

Tags: matlab, nifti

I have two fMRI NIFTI (.nii) files (a region of interest (ROI) mask and an SPM T-contrast), both of which I can read into Matlab using load_nii, giving me two structures. The actual image data within these structures are different sizes and oriented around different origins:

```
SPM = 79*95*69 voxels centered on [40, 57, 26]
ROI = 91*109*91 voxels centered on [46, 64, 37]
```

I need to align these two matrices such that the ROI file corresponds to the correct section of the contrast file. There are several NIFTI-specific functions I can use (pad_nii to add zeros, clip_nii to remove values, from any/several edges), but I'm not sure how to align the two coordinate systems.

Comment: Are you asking how to register these images? Use SPM (or whatever image registration software you like) to register them, or is this your question?

Comment: Not quite; the functional data has already been processed and normalized to MNI space. What I'm trying to do is extract the T-values from the contrast file directly, without having to use another program to do it manually. The issue is that my functional data isn't whole-brain, so I'm not sure how to make sure that the MNI-space ROI matrix is placed over the correct section of the partial-volume SPM matrix

Comment: I am confused, generally we register the fMRI data to MNI to extract statistical masks (or probability maps). You want to do manipulations to the t-values?

Comment: I already have the probability maps. I'm trying to extract statistics (cluster size, peak value, center of mass, etc) from various ROIs

Comment: OK, you have a binary mask (ROI you called it). You also have your probability maps (SPM). I am still confused why these are not in the same space. For example, using FSL, I would have to manually warp my probability maps to MNI space (or anatomical or whatever you like). I guess my question is, on what data set did you draw your mask (clearly not the same one that probability maps were generated)?

Comment: I think what you need to do is apply the transformation (or warp) to take one of your data sets (SPM or ROI) into the space of the other one, so you can derive your stats. Also, FSL would have done this all for you.

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED. I used pad_nii to adjust the origin alignment of the EPI to match that of the ROI.

```
epi_origin =            epi.hdr.hist.originator(1:3);
roi_origin =            roi.hdr.hist.originator(1:3);
origin_diffs =          roi_origin - epi_origin;

opt.pad_from_L =        origin_diffs(1);
opt.pad_from_P =        origin_diffs(2);
opt.pad_from_I =        origin_diffs(3);
epi =                   pad_nii(epi, opt);
```

I think it only works with MNI-normalized data, though it may work with functionally defined ROIs and individually aligned data.

Comment: I am glad you got it work (I am still confused as to the issue, I guess both data sets had the same voxel size at the very least for your method to have worked). In addition, although I am no expert (only worked in the field for 5 years), this does not seem like an elegant solution (more of a quick and dirty method).